# max(row) but #N/A values in row

Tags: excel, max

I am trying to determine the max of a row with 4 columns.

However, that row can have `#N/A` values.

I've read various posts on the web about functions like `sumif()` but there doesn't seem to be a `maxif()` function.

The following link describes how to do what I want to do using `max(if())`:

[Maxif or Minif](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/maxif-or-minif/51916329-dac7-4878-b02b-a8dc87d15c23?auth=1)

However, when I try the following I get `#VALUE` as the result.

```
=MAX(IF(K4:N4<>"#N/A",K4:N4))

Cell K4 = 138
Cell L4 = FALSE
Cell M4 = #N/A
Cell N4 = #N/A
```

The result should be `138`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the #N/A are the result of a formula error, you can try this:

```
=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(K4:N4)),K4:N4))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

See how to ignore errors with the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) without CSE.

```
=aggregate(14, 6, K4:N4, 1)
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>